# JQuery Ajax .done() not being hit

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I am posting data to a method so I can insert a record into SQL, originally I was doing it this way

```
function AddNewItem() {
    var newItem = NewOrderDetailItem(HomeStorage.Keys.TheOrderID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Orders/AddNewOrderDetailItem",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(newItem),
        success: LoadOrderDetailSummary(HomeStorage.Keys.OrderID)
    });
}
```

It works but for some unknown reason, on the success of this, when it called LoadOrderDetailSummary(HomeStorage.Keys.OrderID), it would call the method but it wouldn't catch the newly added record until I refreshed the page.

So I figured that maybe the reason for the record not showing up was maybe a race condition, and as of last night I was lokoing at JQuery Promises and I figured I would give it a shot and came up with this on the button click

```
$('#btnAddNewItem').on('click', function () {

    var newItem = NewOrderDetailItem(HomeStorage.Keys.OrderID);

    var validatable = $("#divOrderDetail").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

    if (validatable.validate()) {
        //var newItem = NewOrderDetailItem();
        //AddNewItem();

        var promised = AddItemPromise();
        promised.done(function () {
            console.log("Promise Done");
            LoadOrderDetailSummary(HomeStorage.Keys.OrderID);
        });

        $('#ntxtSellQty').data("kendoNumericTextBox").value(null);
        $('#ntxtSellPrice').data("kendoNumericTextBox").value(null);
        $('#ntxtMaterialQty').data("kendoNumericTextBox").value(null);
    }

    //console.log(newItem);
});
```

and here is the AddItemPromise();

```
function AddItemPromise() {
    console.log("Promise Called");
    var newItem = NewOrderDetailItem(HomeStorage.Keys.TheOrderID);

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Orders/AddNewOrderDetailItem",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(newItem)
    });
}
```

When I check the console I see the Promise Called, but I am not seeing the Promise Done and since I am not seeing that I don't hit the method that is used for LoadOrderDetailSummary

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the first method wasn't actually working the way you thought it was unless `LoadOrderDetailSummary(...)` returns a function. so... it was probably failing and going to the error callback all along.

Comment: Does the ajax call actually succeed? What if you add a `.fail(...)` case to `promised`?

Comment: @KevinB, The LoadOrderDetailSummary is an ajax call and in that success it passes the returned data to another function that uses the data to populate a grid

Comment: Right. And what i'm saying is the way you've got the first written, it will call LoadOrderDetailSummary before the ajax request is even sent.

Comment: @KevinB, so with the first method that i used, should I put that call to the LoadOrderDetailSummary in the complete?

Comment: i mean... if you did it the same way you did for success, it would have the same result.

Comment: @congrammer, in the promised one I see a textStatus of parseerror

Comment: @KevinB, so how do I fix the problem in either one then? from what I understand is the first way I did it, is actually the old school way and I should be using promises instead

Comment: Move `LoadOrderDetailSummary` into a callback and then make sure your server is responding with valid json (currently it isn't according to said parseerror)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143545/discussion-between-chris-and-kevin-b).